# Why the spinner is not closed after the complete of the API in my UI?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to have a spinner while I am waiting for my API to complete, but here I have a problem. When I press the button `onSave` correctly I saw the spinner, but after my API has completed my spinner is still here. Why is it not working? I want to close the spinner after complete.

```
public onSave() {
  this.isSaving = true
    this.formService.entityForm.markAsPristine();
    this.visaSubmitHandler.execute({ application: this.formService.entityForm.value }).subscribe({
        next: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
            this.stateRehydrationService.clearStateKey(this.formService.key);
            this.visaSuccessHandler.execute({ application: response.entity });
        },
        error: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
            this.formService.entityForm.markAsDirty();
            try {
                for (const error of response.errors) {
                    const propertyName = `${error.propertyName[0].toLowerCase()}${error.propertyName.slice(1)}`
                    const control = this.formService.entityForm.get(propertyName) as AbstractControl;
                    setErrors({ serverError: error.message }, control);
                }

                this.bottomSheet.open(DisplayErrorsComponent, { data: response.errors.map(e => e.message) });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isSaving = false
        }
    })
}
```

```
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="isSaving">
    <div class="spinner-container">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does the function `this.visaSubmitHandler.execute()` do? Does the function complete at all? Did you just try to output a `console.log()` in the complete to see if it is really called?

Comment: I suggest this guide with rxjs: https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/how-to-add-loading-spinner-in-angular-with-rxjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that in your template the variable `isSaving` still has the value `true`.

Therefore,

- either the change detection is disabled by `OnPush` (in this case you do manual `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` right after `this.isSaving = false;`)
- or the observable `this.visaSubmitHandler.execute` does not complete (in this case you can do `this.isSaving = false;` in your `next:`  block or ensure that your observable is closed.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public onSave() {
  this.isSaving = true;

  this.formService.entityForm.markAsPristine();
  
  this.visaSubmitHandler.execute({ application: this.formService.entityForm.value }).subscribe({
    next: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
      this.stateRehydrationService.clearStateKey(this.formService.key);
      this.visaSuccessHandler.execute({ application: response.entity });
    },
    error: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
      this.formService.entityForm.markAsDirty();
      try {
        for (const error of response.errors) {
          const propertyName = `${error.propertyName[0].toLowerCase()}${error.propertyName.slice(1)}`
          const control = this.formService.entityForm.get(propertyName) as AbstractControl;
          setErrors({ serverError: error.message }, control);
        }

        this.bottomSheet.open(DisplayErrorsComponent, { data: response.errors.map(e => e.message) });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
    complete: () => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection
    }
  });
}
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public onSave() {
  this.isSaving = true;

  this.formService.entityForm.markAsPristine();
  
  this.visaSubmitHandler.execute({ application: this.formService.entityForm.value }).subscribe({
    next: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
      this.stateRehydrationService.clearStateKey(this.formService.key);
      this.visaSuccessHandler.execute({ application: response.entity });
    },
    error: (response: IApplicationCreateResponse) => {
      this.formService.entityForm.markAsDirty();
      try {
        for (const error of response.errors) {
          const propertyName = `${error.propertyName[0].toLowerCase()}${error.propertyName.slice(1)}`
          const control = this.formService.entityForm.get(propertyName) as AbstractControl;
          setErrors({ serverError: error.message }, control);
        }

        this.bottomSheet.open(DisplayErrorsComponent, { data: response.errors.map(e => e.message) });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
    complete: () => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection
    }
  });
}
```